# How is the Swedish income tax when compared to that of the US?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, sweden

Calculating the income tax does not seem easy like solving a single formula. I tried to use online calculators, but the results widely varied by sites, so it may be more accurate to ask someone who has knowledge on taxes. Which of the following could be said about the income taxes of Sweden and the US?

1. They are more or less the same.
2. Sweden's is generally higher.
3. US's is generally higher.
4. Sweden's is higher for a certain range (such as people with low income, or billionaires).
5. US's is higher for a certain range.
6. None of above.

This is not a homework or a test problem. I just personally want to know about it, since many people in the US seem to think Sweden's welfare is ideal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_Sweden#Income_tax  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_tax_in_the_United_States

Comment: #6, though #4 and #5 are probably the next best answers. There are too many variations to make blanket statements.